# Section roman and section cross-reference arabic

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering

I want to change just the section cross-reference from roman to Arabic numbers in a paper using the IEEE template. An MWE of my problem is

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\begin{document} 
Section~\ref{sec-test} is incorrect. 
\section{My Test}\label{sec-test}
\end{document}
```

The text showed in the phrase must be: "Section 1 is incorrect." (Arabic number) But the displayed text is "Section I is incorrect." (Roman number) The section title must remain "Section I" (Roman number).

Does someone know how to set this up?

Comment: why do you want to confuse your readers like that?

Comment: It is a requirement from the journal in which I'm publishing it

Comment: Then why don't they provide the code for it?

Answer (score 1):

The specification is quite bizarre: if a section is numbered “I” (with a Roman numeral), also cross-references should follow the scheme.

Anyway, it is quite easy to provide the required numbering scheme, because `IEEEtran` detaches title numbering from the related counter's representation: for the numbering of `\section` it uses `\thesectiondis`. Thus the following works.

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesectiondis{\Roman{section}.}

\begin{document}

Section~\ref{sec-test} is incorrect.

\section{My Test}\label{sec-test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example updates `\refstepcounter` in a way that re-stores `\@currentlabel` using `\arabic` rather than `\Roman` specifically when the `section` counter is being stepped. Both `\subsection`s and `\subsubsection`s require similar treatment and have been added as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 

\makeatletter
\let\oldrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
  \oldrefstepcounter{#1}% Regular \refstepcounter
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}=0
    % Update \@currentlabel for \section to be \arabic
    \edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{section}}%
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{subsection}=0
      % Update \@currentlabel for \subsection to match default + \arabic section counter
      \edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{section}-\Alph{subsection}}%
    \else
      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{subsubsection}=0
        % Update \@currentlabel to match default for \subsubsection + \arabic for section
        \edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{section}-\Alph{subsection}\arabic{subsubsection}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

Section~\ref{sec-test} is correct.

\section{My Test}\label{sec-test}

\end{document}
```

This has not been extensively tested and therefore comes with no guarantee.